# String[].split(String regex) will not split at all when using String as regex

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, split

I'm trying to read a polynomial in my format that would add together constant with the same variable and for that I need to split out constant and variable apart from "x^" but when I try to use the .split() method it doesn't split at all and just puts the whole string into the first cell of the array.

```java
// Splitting terms into constants and variables:
String splitTerms[][] = new String[terms.size()][2];
for (int i = 0; i < terms.size(); i++) {
    String tempTerm = terms.get(i);
    if (tempTerm.indexOf("x^") >= 0) {
        // Here is where the problem occurs:
        splitTerms[i] = tempTerm.split("x^");
    }
    else if (tempTerm.indexOf("x") >= 0) {
        splitTerms[i][0] = tempTerm.substring(0, tempTerm.length()-1);
        splitTerms[i][1] = "1";
    }
    else {
        splitTerms[i][0] = tempTerm;
        splitTerms[i][1] = "0";
    }
}
```

If anyone knows why this happens or what do I do to fix it, I would really appreciate the help!

Comment: `split()` uses regex, and `^` is a special character

Comment: Escape "^": `"x\\^"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split()` uses regex, and `^` is a special character, so you'll need to escape the `^`:

```
tempTerm.split("x\\^");
```

Which for the `String` "2x^2" will output:

```
[2, 2]
```

Comment: Or: `tempTerm.split(Pattern.quote("x^"))`.